# How can I add cooldown to this proximityprompt for local player only

Tags: debugging, scripting, roblox, proximity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXBwA.png)

I want to add a cooldown to the proximitypropmt for only local players, meaning that there will be no cooldown for other players until they use the proximity too, thanks in adavance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTXol.png)
I tried using this method and it kinda worked but for some reason it duplicated all the existing "pizzas" in my invenotry whenever i triedd to grab a new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a server script you can put the following inside a localscript and place it inside the StarterPlayerScripts. This way the server does not have to track who triggered the proximity.

```lua
local db = false
local proxy = [YourProxyPath].Triggered:Connect(function(plr)
    if not db then 
        db = true
        print("triggered") 
        -- tell server to give items to the player using remoteEvent
    end
    wait(5)
    db = false
end)
```